# remote object server is never synchronized

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm

hi i cannot seem to get realm synced with the realm object server i am working xamarin and it's working great localing i just can't seem to sync to the cloud , not even the schema
my code is:

```
  var credentials = Credentials.UsernamePassword(usernameField.Text.ToLower(), passField.Text, createUser: true);
            var authURL = new System.Uri("https://game-object.us1.cloud.realm.io/");
            var user = await User.LoginAsync(credentials, authURL);
            var serverURL = new System.Uri("realm://game-object.us1.cloud.realm.io/~/default");
            var configuration = new SyncConfiguration(user, serverURL);
            var permission= await user.GetGrantedPermissionsAsync(Recipient.CurrentUser,millisecondTimeout:2111);
            var realm = Realm.GetInstance(configuration);
            bool m;
            if (realm.Config == configuration)
            m=true;

            var realmSession= realm.GetSession();
            var state = realmSession.State;
            var permissionCondition = PermissionCondition.UserId(user.Identity);
            /* await user.ApplyPermissionsAsync(permissionCondition, "realm://game-object.us1.cloud.realm.io/~/default", AccessLevel.Write);
             permission = await user.GetGrantedPermissionsAsync(Recipient.CurrentUser, millisecondTimeout: 2111);
            */
            var players = realm.All<Player>();


            realm.Write(() =>
            {
                realm.Add(new Player { Health = 1, name = "apex" });

            });


            var count = players.Count();
```

Comment: It might be that your sync session is closed too early. Consider adding a progress notification so you can ensure not to close the session before data has been uploaded. See https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/#progress-notifications.

Comment: no , i debugged my session state and it's active

Comment: Wasn't reading carefully earlier. It seems that you are mixing `https` and `realm`. Try to either use `http` + `realm` or `https` + `realms`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i feel embraced, but the reason i wasn't getting updates is because the client object browser doesn't auto update